# Multiple Bucket Filling

Tags: algorithm

I have two bucket with each having carrying capacity.

```
Bucket A: 100 kg
Bucket B: 110 kg
```

I have multiple weights:

```
Weight W1: 20 kg
Weight W2: 40 kg
Weight W3: 90 kg
Weight W4: 80 kg
```

What I want is to fill bucket with maximum weights

```
Bucket A <- W3
Bucket B <- W1, W4
```

If bucket is only one, it is like KnapSack problem.

For multiple bucket with different capacity, I am not able to solve it.

Comment: Im currently thinking about it how to solve. First thing that comes to my mind is solving Ax = b A is weight x is 1-0's and b is buckets when you solve with x = [At * A]' * At * b you will get x's with floating point and you can round them maybe but that does not solve %100 so I moved to forcing the solution for each possibility but even with this 4×2 system there are 132 possibilities. Im still thinking

Comment: @İhsanCemilÇiçek thanks for looking in problem. I will post answer if I am able to solve/search that.

Comment: seems to me NP hard problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689236/knapsack-with-multiple-bags-and-items-having-only-weight

Answer (score 0):

Find out each baskets free space if you put the highest weight you can possibly put to that  bucket.

Put the weight to the bucket that has the maximum,

```
weight / SpaceLeftAfter
```

I'll post a code when I'm at a computer.