# Is there an algorithm to solve this problem efficiently? Is it NP-Complete?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have two arrays.  One array represents items.  The other array represents customers with money.  I need to find if all items can be purchased.  An item can only be purchased by one person.  But multiple items can be purchased by a single customer.

Example,

```
Items: [10, 20, 30]
Customers: [40, 20]
Yes. Customer 1 can purchase items 1 and 3.  Customer 2 can purchase item 2.

Items: [10, 20]
Customers: [15, 15]
No. Customer 1 can purchase item 1, but Customer 2 cannot purchase item 2.
```

Edit: I think this may be np-complete since it seems like a variation of the bin packing problem.

Comment: Are there any other requirements? Why is it customer 2 that gets to purchase item 2 in the first example, rather than customer 1?

Comment: This looks at least as difficult as bin-packing (if all customers have the same amount of money, this is exactly the classical bin-packing).

Comment: Related (duplicate?) https://stackoverflow.com/q/23689236/2095090

Comment: (@VincentvanderWeele: that's an odd question for naming the same *n* for bags and items.)

Comment: See also: [multiple subset sum problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_subset_sum). This question may fare better over on [COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Beware nits being picked, such as NP applying to *decision* problems.

Comment: What have you got so far? (We tend to suggest fixes to answers, not to start the answers.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by use of iteration over Knapsack problem with same value and weight  for each element.

```
Let E as elements
Let V as item values for all elements
Let M the number of Customers
for i = 0 to M
   W = Customers[i]
   Knapsack(E,V,W)
   E = E - {funded elements for this W}  
   i= i +1
end for

If E is empty print YES
else print NO
```

If Items has **N** element and Customers has **M** elements the time complexity for recursive method is **M * O(2<sup>N</sup>)**. But you can use dynamic programming to solve it roughly in **O(M * N * W<sub>M</sub>)** Which **W<sub>M</sub>** is the average of customer budgets (in you first example 30). So you can solve it in polynomial time complexity.

I provide you a dynamic programming sample to solve your problem in Java. This code may have bug and you can improve this code as well.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {

    // A utility function that returns
    // maximum of two integers
    static int max(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a > b) ? a : b;
    }
  
    static void knapSack(int W, ArrayList<Integer> wtArr, int n)
    {
        int i, w;
        int K[][] = new int[n + 1][W + 1];
        
        int wt[] = wtArr.stream().mapToInt(ix -> ix).toArray();
        int[] val = new int[n];
        System.arraycopy(wt, 0, val, 0, n);


        // Build table K[][] in bottom up manner
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            for (w = 0; w <= W; w++) {
                if (i == 0 || w == 0)
                    K[i][w] = 0;
                else if (wt[i - 1] <= w)
                    K[i][w] = Math.max(val[i - 1] +
                              K[i - 1][w - wt[i - 1]], K[i - 1][w]);
                else
                    K[i][w] = K[i - 1][w];
            }
        }
 
        // stores the result of Knapsack
        int res = K[n][W];
        //System.out.println("\nres = "+res);
 
        int j=0;
        w = W;
        for (i = n; i > 0 && res > 0; i--) {
 
            // either the result comes from the top
            // (K[i-1][w]) or from (val[i-1] + K[i-1]
            // [w-wt[i-1]]) as in Knapsack table. If
            // it comes from the latter one/ it means
            // the item is included.
            if (res == K[i - 1][w]) {
                //System.out.print(wt[i - 1] + "<< ");
                continue;
            }
            else {
 
                // This item is included.
                System.out.print(wt[i - 1] + " ");
                wtArr.remove(i-1);
                // Since this weight is included its
                // value is deducted
                res = res - val[i - 1];
                w = w - wt[i - 1];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(wtArr);
    }
    

    // Driver code
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> wt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        wt.addAll(Arrays.asList(10, 20 , 30));
        int cu[] = new int[] {40 , 20};
        for (int i=0; i<cu.length; i++) {
            int n = wt.size();
            int W = cu[i];
            
            knapSack(W, wt, n);
        }
        
        if(wt.size() > 0)
            System.out.println("NO");
        else 
            System.out.println("YES");
        
    }
}
```

See [Java Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/rT6OFeAiKk) for test by yourself.