# how to efficiently handle multiple dictionaries to match specific criteria for a patient requirements without going through all possibilities?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, random

Disclaimer: Bear with me for four and half minutes. what might look ridiculous, it's because I am a doctor of medicine not a programmer, though I am kinda addicted since first learning basic in 1996.

So, I am trying to design an application to help me (and my fellows) to quickly be able to design a meal plan for a patient.
the science in this is pretty straight forward:
1 - Age, Weight, Height, Gender, Fat percentage -> BMI, BMR -> Estimated Energy Requirement (EER)
2 - EER -> Calories (Carbs, Protein, Fat) -> Grams requirements (Carbs, Protein, Fat) <<== that's the goal.
so far, nothing fancy. the problem arise from the last point. there's no easy or scientific way to translate patients grams requirements into a meal. there are ton's of tables that's different on country level, and hospital levels with lots of variations.
That's because there are usually 7 classes of food:

```
[legume, milk, vegetables, fruits, starch, meat, oil]
```

and each class of food there's specific serving size. and each serving unit represent specific values for each component in (Carbs, Protein, Fat) (which I need to match it with the patient's needs).

**for example:**

```
1 milk serving ={"carbs":15, "ptn":8, "fat":3}
```

```
1 fruit serving ={"carbs":15, "ptn":0, "fat":0}
```

so using only milk and fruits, if the patient grams requirement is (Carbs=31, Ptn=10, Fat=4), I'll try to create a meal with one milk serving + one fruit serving = (carbs=30, ptn=8, fat=3) to closely matches the patients needs (with 10% margin of error).

so that's the problem.
I tried to approach it systematically but it needed like 10e7 trial - i think -.
I tried to brutforce the values randomly using some logic, and that gave some results with 40% success and 60% infinite loop.

I have:
1 list of dictionaries 'Food' =  [legume, milk, vegetables, fruits, starch, meat, oil]
each dictionary contains some values for {"carbs":X, "ptn":Y, "fat":Z}
then I have patient needs dictionary: {"carbs":Xp, "ptn":Yp, "fat":Zp}
then I created an aggregate dictionary to add a random dictionary from the food list.
then check the total value of the aggregate dictionary.if it's overshooting the patient's needs, i'll remove it from the aggregate dictionary. if it's still below the patient's needs, then I add it.
in the end, it returns the aggregate dictionary (to compare it with patients needs) and how many food items have been used from each food class.

but that's not it. there is another problem with the random approach that the computer cheat its way to match the aggregate dict with the patient's requirement. so instead of creating a balanced diet, it would suggest creating a meal with 20 servings of oil, and 15 of starch. Theoretically it matches the patient requirements. but not practical.

I tried to add many logic to force the function to use the unused fooditem, and at least to use it once. also limiting certain items to maximum number of servings. I also tried to create some bias using np.random.choice ... didn't work.
here is a sample function with sample data:

Data:

```
ref_dict = {"carbs":274,"ptn":82,"fat":85} #patient's needs
aggre_dict = {"carbs":0,"ptn":0,"fat":0} #basket

legum ={"carbs":15, "ptn":7, "fat":0}
milk ={"carbs":15, "ptn":8, "fat":3}
veg ={"carbs":5, "ptn":2, "fat":0}
fruits ={"carbs":15, "ptn":0, "fat":0}
starch ={"carbs":15, "ptn":3, "fat":1}
meat ={"carbs":0, "ptn":7, "fat":3}
oil ={"carbs":0, "ptn":0, "fat":5}
```

Function:

```
def update_aggregate_dict(ref_dict, aggre_dict, legum, milk, veg, fruits, starch, meat, oil, margin):
    dict_list = [legum, milk, veg, fruits, starch, meat, oil]
    dict_count = {'legum': 0, 'milk': 0, 'veg': 0, 'fruits': 0, 'starch': 0, 'meat': 0, 'oil': 0}
    counter = 0
    chosen_dict_A = random.choice(dict_list, size=1000)
    
    sm_list=[]
    while True:
        # Choose a random dictionary from the list
        while True:
            chosen_dict = choice(chosen_dict_A)
            dict_name = [k for k, v in locals().items() if v is chosen_dict][0]
            
            if dict_count[dict_name]==0: #make sure to use every food class at least once
                sm_list.append(dict_name)
                break
            elif len(set(sm_list))==7: #make sure to track the use of all 7 classes
                break

        if (dict_name == "oil" and dict_count[dict_name] < 10) \
                or (dict_name == "veg" and dict_count[dict_name] < 7)\
                or (dict_name == "fruits" and dict_count[dict_name] < 7)  \
                or (dict_name == "starch" and dict_count[dict_name] < 15) \
                or (dict_name == "milk" and dict_count[dict_name] < 4)\
                or (dict_name == "legum" and dict_count[dict_name] < 7)\
                or (dict_name == "meat" and dict_count[dict_name] < 11): #make sure that each food class doesn't exceed certain limit
            if any(aggre_dict[key] > ref_dict[key] for key in ref_dict):
                if dict_count[dict_name] > 0: #overshooting
                    dict_count[dict_name] -= 1
                    for key in chosen_dict:
                        aggre_dict[key] -= chosen_dict[key]
            else: #undershooting 
                dict_count[dict_name] += 1
                for key in chosen_dict:
                    aggre_dict[key] += chosen_dict[key]

        # Check if the values in the aggregate dictionary are within the margin
        if all(abs(aggre_dict[key] - ref_dict[key]) <= margin for key in ref_dict):
            within_margin = True
        else:
            within_margin = False

        # If the values in the aggregate dictionary are within the margin, Exit
        if within_margin:
            return aggre_dict, dict_count

        # handle the infinite loops
        counter += 1
        if counter > 1000000:
            print("not found: breaking!")
            break

    return aggre_dict, dict_count
```

sample return:

```
{'legum': 0, 'milk': 4, 'veg': 7, 'fruits': 7, 'starch': 5, 'meat': 3, 'oil': 10}
{'carbs': 275, 'ptn': 82, 'fat': 76}
```

this results means that the patient needs to drink 50ml of oil, and 1 liter of milk [besides the others], which is unrealistic.

the question is: How to handle this more efficiently, and create more balanced results (or skewed based on my needs) without going through 10e7 probability or going randomly ?

thank you.

Comment: You might like to read up on "The backpack problem with multi-binning".  Alas I think it is  NP-Hard.  You might try this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689236/knapsack-with-multiple-bags-and-items-having-only-weight

Comment: Thank you for your input. it's interesting how simple procedure could be classified as "NP-Hard"! However, I don't think my case exactly match with "the backpack problem", since I can use "a fraction of a serve" to step up or down the fitting process instead of using a whole unit. I believe it's doable, but I am lacking the knowledge to get through it programmatically.

Comment: what if you search for the closest match [for fitting in margin] after removing because of over-shooting? I think that should reduce the iterations by quite a bit...